# Does apt-get upgrade checksum deb files?

Tags: apt

Does apt-get upgrade checksum deb files?

If yes then where exactly it checks? After downloading a deb file or while installing it? Does it download the checksum from the repository or is the checksum embedded in deb file itself? Does software-updated gui behave like apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: it downloads signed checksums from the same repository as the package, verifies that the signature matches an accepted key, and finally verifies the checksum of the .deb file.

The GUI calls `apt` in the background and in effect does the same.